# Get Physical path of Virtual Directory in Window Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, windows-services, virtual-directory

In my IIS server I have a **Virtual Directory** *("docPath")* which is mapped with a physical folder of my machine.

I have a **Window Service** and from this service I need to get the Physical path of Virtual directory (created on IIS) i.e. *"docPath"*.

Since this is Windows service so I do not have **[HTTPContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext(v=vs.110).aspx)** object and I cannot use the `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/docPath");`

**This is what I've tried so far:**

I have tried to use the [ServerManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager(v=vs.90).aspx) from [Microsoft.Web.Administration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration(v=vs.90).aspx).

```
ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager();
Site site = serverManager.Sites.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "Default Web Site");
Application myApp = site.Applications["/docPath"];
```

But in [Sites](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager.sites(v=vs.90).aspx) only web application created on IIS server are coming and not Virtual directories.

Also, `System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath` is also not working.

**Could anybody let me know how can I get physical path of a Virtual Directory in Windows Service?**

Comment: You could have the service send an HTTP request to a URL on IIS that simply outputs the return value of `MapPath()`. Then the service can read that response.

Comment: Try `System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath`.

Comment: @JanneP I have already tried this and this is also not working.

Comment: @RemyLebeau How could I do this any lead?

Comment: Are you sure it's preferable for your windows service to have to know website and virtual directory names (either hard coded or via configuration) vs just being configured with the directory it should use directly?

Comment: Since the web app can resolve the physical path of the virtual directory, why don't you implement a web method in it that gives out this path, then have the windows service use it to get the physical path just as @RemyLebeau had suggested.

Comment: @Owuor I have a question here, you cannot access the virtual directory from browser means for my case if I tried to access **http://localhost/docPath** then it gives error **HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.** And if tried to access  this url from web method it gives me error. Then how could I do this using WebMethod?

Comment: @GeekyNinja I have posted an example as an answer

Comment: @GeekyNinja Instead of using a whole wbpage for this task, I have used a Generic Handler, since this will be lighter and better for the task.

Answer (score 0):

Add a generic handler to your web app, then have it return to you the physical path. In the generic handler you can have this code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for PhysicalPathHandler
    /// </summary>
    public class PhysicalPathHandler : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

            context.Response.Write(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("docPath"));
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this in the windows service.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("your-web-app-web-address-to-the-generic-handler"); //e.g. http://localhost:2950/PhysicalPathHandler.ashx

            string physicalPath = string.Empty; //this will store the physical path
            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet);

                using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, encoding))
                    physicalPath= reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
```

Remember to include the following namespaces into the windows service

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
```

Comment: Please don't use the code snippets if you're not posting code that is javascript and can actually run in the browser, directly from your answer.

Comment: If the windows service is not written in .NET, you can't use HttpWebRequest, so use a different tactic to send an HTTP request. Such as using the WinInet API, or any 3rd party socket communication library, or even just WinSock directly since this would be a very simple HTTP request to format manually.